# Как посчитать сумму числовых значений в столбце?

Tags: php, mysql

как посчитать сумму числовых значений в столбце 'cost' из таблицы MySql, чтобы в переменную заносилось в данном случае значение 4850 и выводилась?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Сумма по колонке:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM myTable;
```

Comment: я не понимаю как вывести саму сумму, само значение, которое он должен посчитать

Comment: Сделайте запрос на подобии `SELECT SUM(cost) AS cost_sum FROM myTable;` и работаете с суммой как с обычной колонкой `cost_sum`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
     require_once("../connect.php");
     $query = "SELECT SUM(cost)
     FROM comments";
     $com = $pdo->query($query);
     while($comments = $com->fetch()) {
     echo
     "<span>{$comments['SUM(cost)']}</span>";
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(cost) AS sum_cost     FROM comments; $comments['sum_cost']

Comment: Согласен, так лучше.